# docker - addressing environment variables used in parent image

Tags: postgresql, docker

I need to create `plpythonu` extension on the `postgres:10.3` image. For this, I extended the image with an installation command:

```
FROM postgres:10.3

RUN apt update && apt install -y postgresql-plpython-10
```

Now I need to run a `psql` command `create extension plpythonu;`. But at this point the postgres server is not running yet, so when running `docker build .` I get an error:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN psql -c "create extension plpythonu;";
 ---> Running in 037066c120ea
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How do I fit this command in? And is there a way to do this without copypasting the entire `docker-entrypoint.sh` from the original postgres image? Maybe there's a way to specify this in docker-compose?

Comment: i created it with any error

Answer (score 0):

When step-2 is over you Postgres database down, that is why in Step-3 database is not running.
You can combine step-2 and step-3 together.

```
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y postgresql-plpython-10 && \
    psql -c "create extension plpythonu;"
```

It means && (logical and) if previous commands successfully over then only execute next one.

Comment: the result is the same: my postgres db is down even during step 2.

Comment: you have to start database using pg_ctl start ::::RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y postgresql-plpython-10 &&  pg_ctl start && \
    psql -c "create extension plpythonu;"